# Where IIS Express deploys files of ASP NET MVC Application launched from VS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-express

Where IIS Express deploys files of my ASP .NET MVC application when I run it from Visual Studio?
[image]

Comment: usually in bin/debug or bin/release folder of your solution. Why tho?

Comment: If not ASP.NET Core, IIS Express uses your source folder by default.